# Browser Link not refreshing page in Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, visual-studio-2019, blazor, asp.net-core-3.0

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/using-browserlink?view=aspnetcore-3.0) documentation to enable Browser Link  and set up a new Blazor project (targeting `.NET Core 3`) using the provided template (running Visual Studio 16.3.9, which is latest as of writing).

[image]

As mentioned in the documentation I have installed the nuget package `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink` and added the middleware to my `Startup.cs`

```
public class Startup 

    // ...

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }

        // ...
```

When starting the application and opening the `Browser Link Dashboard` I see the browser as connected:

[image]

However when making a change, e.g adding `<Counter />` to `Index.razor`, the change is not getting reflected in my browser window.

When I hit the refresh button from within Visual Studio, the browser window seems to refresh, but does not show the changes. The same applies when *manually* refreshing the page by using the browsers refresh button.

Even more interesting is the fact, that when **not** running in Debug mode the refresh seems to work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `blazor` does not support live reloading with debugger(F5) but without debugger (ctrl-F5) works.

Refer to

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/15613#issuecomment-430810677

[Why does page not update after refresh when .cshtml changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54106058/why-does-page-not-update-after-refresh-when-cshtml-changes)