# Blazor routing and layout when inside an area

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an existing MVC project and I am trying to integrate Blazor into it. To do this I had to upgrade from .NET Core 2.1 to 3.1 and change a few things in my startup class to get the application working as it was before.

After sorting all the upgrade stuff out, I've now added the hub  to my `Configure` startup method:

```
...

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "areas",
        pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
});
```

... and the server sign Blazor services registration:

```
...

services
    .AddMvc(options =>
    {
        ...
    })
    .AddRazorOptions(o =>
    {
        ...
    })
    .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        ...
    });

services.AddServerSideBlazor();
```

Finally, I've added the Blazor JS script to my `~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` view:

```
<script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
```

I'm struggling to figure out what the `@page` value should be for a new Razor Component when the component is within a view.

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

Everything inside the `Pages` folder is new.

Here is the contents of `Index.razor`:

```
@page "/"

<h3>Sales Homepage</h3>

@code {

}
```

I've tried the following for the `@page` route value:

- "/"
- "/Index"
- "/Pricing/Sales/"
- "/Pricing/Sales/Index"

None of these have worked - I just get a page not found error.

I'm also not sure how I'm supposed to use my existing layout in `~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` with these new components.

I've had a look at the scaffolded Blazor template project in Visual Studio and also checked the docs but haven't found this particularly useful as it's all focused on brand new Blazor projects.

Answer (score 9):

To add blazor pages support, you also need to add call to `MapFallbackToPage` (for Razor Pages project) or `MapFallbackToController`(for MVC project) in startup endpoint configuration.

For MVC project, refer to below steps:

*1.Create a `App.razor` under `Views` folder*

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing

<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="routeData" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <h1>Page not found</h1>
        <p>Sorry, but there's nothing here!</p>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

2.Create a `_Host.cshml` file under `Views/Shared`

```
@page "/blazor"

@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<app>
    @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<App>(RenderMode.ServerPrerendered))
</app>
```

> MyApp
>
> ——Views
>
> ————Shared
>
> ——————Host.cshtml
>
> ————App.razor

3.*Add call to `MapFallbackToController` and point it to the new `_Host.cshtml`:*

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToController("Host","Home");
        });
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Host()
    {
        return View("_Host");
    }
}
```

*4.Index.razor* test with "/"

```
@page "/"

<h3>Sales Homepage</h3>
```

For Razor Pages project, just create `_Host.cshtml` and `App.razor` under `Pages` folder, and use `endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host")` in `startup.cs`

More clear steps，refer to https://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/combining-razor-blazor-pages-single-asp-net-core-3-application

Comment: Thanks. I have made progress and can now see my Sales component content under `Pricing/Sales`. However, if I change something in the razor component and refresh the page, nothing changes. Any ideas?

Comment: @Andy Furniss Do you change the component without rebuilding the project?blazor does not support live reloading with debugger(F5) but without debugger (ctrl-F5) works.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58861948/browser-link-not-refreshing-page-in-chrome/58871880#58871880

Comment: Thank you. No debugger and ctrl+F5 seems to work as you say. However, before I hit ctrl+F5, I get the following error in the console `Connection disconnected with error 'Error: WebSocket closed with status code: 1006 ().` which suggests it's trying to live reload but failing. Is this something else I can fix?

Comment: Does this work for Static Web App? seems to fail deploying onto Azure static web app

Answer (score 2):

You must:

1. Define another namespace for Areas/Pages to prevent name conflict with main branch without Areas.
2. Place to you Areas new App.razor component. The same if layout is the same.
3. Place your page with @route attribute on top of each page in Areas/Pages and Areas/Shared
4. Place _Host.rasor, the same if layout is the same. But you must changing href attibutes in header (add ~).
5. Add to startup new route

```
endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("admin_route", "Admin", "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
```

6. Main point to hope to Areas is: you must break existing SignalR connection and navigate to Areas not from simple click, but the same way

```
navigationManager.NavigateTo("/Admin/", forceLoad: true);
```

This is workable pattern, I always use it and it working fine.

Comment: Could you please. Give us more details, your answer seems very interesting to me.